# Python list sort reverse order

Tags: python, list, sorting, sortedlist

I am trying to create some sort of scoreboard based on the highest values. I have added the reverse=true flag but it still prints as ascending rather than descending order. I have tried changing the code to use the sort() method as well but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
def sort(results):
import csv
import operator

sort = open(results,'r')
newsort = sorted(sort,key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)

for eachline in newsort:
    print (eachline)
```

Bob,5,memory

Blod,1,memory

candy,5,memory

Candy,4,memory

Candice,1,memory

Candybdjf,5,memory

is what prints, even though i have asked it to be sorted by index 1?

Comment: `5, 5, 4` _is_ descending rather than ascending order. 4 is smaller than 5.

Comment: Your items are just the lines in the file which are strings and key `1` means the second letter in each line. `o`, `a`, `a` is the correct reverse order.

Comment: Index 1 means 2nd column, if you want 1st column, then use 0

Comment: so should I use itemgetter[1], reverse=True  instead? I want it to sort the values in column to in descending order to show a scoreboard.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your edited code is that you're not actually reading the file as a CSV:

```
sort = open(results,'r')
newsort = sorted(sort,key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

This is sorting each line as a string. Which means `itemgetter(1)` is getting character #1 in that string. So, because `'o' > 'l' > 'a'`, that's how things get sorted.

If you want to read a file as a CSV file, you can't just `import` the CSV module, you have to *use* it:

```
sort = open(results,'r')
rows = csv.reader(sort)
newsort = sorted(rows,key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

Now you're sorting on column #1 rather than character #1: `'5' > '4' > '1'`, which is what you wanted.

---

However, if that second column is meant to be sorted *numerically*, so that, e.g., `10 > 2`, you need to do more. Because those columns are strings, and `'10' < '2'` as strings.

If you want to actually use those values as numbers, you'll want to convert them as you read them:

```
sort = open(results,'r')
rows = ((name, int(num), thing) for (name, num, thing) in csv.reader(sort))
newsort = sorted(rows,key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

If you only need them to be numbers for the purpose of sorting, you can do it a bit more simply:

```
sort = open(results,'r')
rows = csv.reader(sort)
newsort = sorted(rows, key=lambda: int(row[1]), reverse = True)
```

---

If you don't understand the generator expression above:

```
rows = ((name, int(num), thing) for (name, num, thing) in csv.reader(sort))
```

… we can break it down.

First, a generator expression is just a lazy version of a list comprehension—it produces the same values, but it produces them on demand, instead of building a list of them. And the equivalent list comprehension is the same thing, but with square brackets:

```
rows = [(name, int(num), thing) for (name, num, thing) in csv.reader(sort)]
```

That probably isn't any easier to understand if you've never seen a comprehension before. But you can turn any list comprehension into an explicit loop around `append`:

```
rows = []
for (name, num, thing) in csv.reader(sort):
    rows.append((name, int(num), thing))
```

If that still isn't clear, let's break things down further:

```
rows = []
for row in csv.reader(sort):
    # unpack the three columns of the row into three separate variables
    name, num, thing = row
    # convert the string in the middle column into an int
    num = int(num)
    # put the three variables back into a single sequence
    row = (name, num, thing)
    # add it to rows
    rows.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, could you explain what the following bit does: rows = ((name, int(num), thing) for (name, num, thing) in csv.reader(sort))

Comment: @KCho Edited; does it make sense now?

Comment: Very much. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (assuming your second column name is 'Idx'):

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter('Idx'), reverse=True):
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'Bob'), ('Idx', '5'), ('Memory', 'memory')])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'candy'), ('Idx', '5'), ('Memory', 'memory')])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'Candy'), ('Idx', '4'), ('Memory', 'memory')])
```

If you don't want to use csv reader you can try something like this:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    for row in sorted(csvfile, key=lambda x: x.split(',')[1], reverse=True):
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
Bob,5,memory
candy,5,memory
Candy,4,memory
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I haven't actually named the columns as I am not sure how to do that... Would I need to name the columns first? Am i not just able to sort it using [1]?

Comment: @KCho no, because then you sort based on the second character in each line. These are: `o l a a a a`

Comment: @KCho `DictReader` can be very handy, but you do need to name the columns. If you haven't done that in the CSV file itself, you can do it in your code, by passing a `fieldnames` argument to the constructor. (See the docs for details.)